# Codeigniter command line can't inset to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I have this function on 'myproject/controllers/sample.php'

```
public function callTest() 
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table_name (client_id, subscription_id, platform, device) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)");

    $this->load->view('sample');
}
```

Whenever I run it on the browser (localhost/index.php/sample/callTest), it successfully runs and inserts the data on the table, but when I use command line (php index.php sample callTest), the SQL won't run.

I removed the database part and it shows the code for the view, which I think is correct. But if I put a database logic to it, it won't run and the output is blank. No error logs also.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing an argument?
My codeigniter version is 2.2.6.
This is my reference https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/cli.html

Edited: Aril 17,2017

I just figured out that in some of environment, the command line above works. I suspect that the cause of this was me converting PHP 5.5 to 5.6 in Ubuntu 14, some of the dependencies might not be configured correctly.

Comment: If you are using Linux you may have problems with privileges - try to run this script as a root or www-data

Comment: On the cli, does the view load? It should and you will see the html fo the view in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify controller and function name as well,

**Example**

```
php index.php/sample/callTest
```

Also you need to set one config variable as below

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'
```

Read the document answer is hidden there.

> Now normally you would visit the your site using a URL similar to
>   this:
>
> example.com/index.php/tools/message/to